# Exiting itself from games

Tags: motorola-moto-g

I have had this phone for a few years now and it has only started doing this a couple of months ago. I downloaded Five Nights at Freddy's 2 Demo (I'm a massive game freak) and after about 2 minutes of opening the app and started playing, it just exited itself to the home screen. This has happened multipule times with clash of clans as well. I really dont know what to do. I have tried turning it off and on again but it didn't work. What should I do?

Comment: "A few years"? The Moto G was only announced in November 2013...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crashing to the home screen is an indication of the RAM in the device running out, you should try to reduce the amount of programs that are running in RAM and that are on the phone.